# Запуск nginx для viberbot, права доступа

Tags: node.js, nginx, viber, viber-api

Есть проект viberbot написан на node.js, необходимо переместить его из одной инфраструктуры в другую.
Все работы выполнены, для теста нужно сделать get-запрос урла https://bot.com/sss/webhook/viber и получить ответ "200".
В коде такой урл есть, но при запросе я получаю "403 Forbidden".
Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?